# contour integral piecewise

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $$\int \limits_\gamma \frac1{z-1}dz$$
along the path:

$$\gamma(t) = \begin{cases}(1+i)t, & 0\leq t\leq 1 \\\\ t+i(2-t), & 1\leq t \leq2\end{cases}$$

I know how to do simple questions of these but I am unsure about this one. This is what I tried. Let $f(z)$ represent the equation given in the integral.

$$\gamma'(t) = \begin{cases}t+i, & 0\leq t\leq 1 \\\\ 1-i, & 1\leq t \leq2\end{cases}$$
and
$$f(\gamma(t)) = \begin{cases}\frac1{(1+i)t-1}, & 0\leq t\leq 1 \\\\ \frac1{t+i(2-t)-1}, & 1\leq t \leq2\end{cases}$$

Then what do you do?

Comment: Given a curve $\alpha\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb C$ and a function $g$, by definition $\displaystyle \int _\alpha g=\int _a^bg(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t)\mathrm dt$ when the RHS makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually $\gamma'(t) = 1 + i$ for $0 \le t < 1$ and $\gamma'(t) = 1 - i$ for $1 < t \le 2$. So your contour integral becomes

$$\int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\, dt + \int_1^2 f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\, dt = \int_0^1 \frac{1 + i}{(1 + i)t - 1}\, dt + \int_1^2 \frac{1 - i}{t - 1 + (2-t)i}\, dt.$$

To evaluate the last two integrals, express

$$\frac{1 + i}{(1 + i)t - 1} = \frac{(1 + i)[(1 - i)t - 1]}{|(1 + i)t - 1|^2} = \frac{2t - 1 - i}{(t - 1)^2 + t^2} = \frac{2t - 1 - i}{2t^2 - 2t + 1}$$

and

$$\frac{1 - i}{(t - 1) + (2 - t)i} = \frac{(1 - i)[(t - 1) - (2 - t)i}{|(t - 1) + (2 - t)i|^2} = \frac{2t - 3 - i}{(t - 1)^2 + (2-t)^2} = \frac{2t - 3 - i}{2t^2 - 6t + 5}.$$

We have

\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{2t - 1 - i}{2t^2 - 2t + 1} \, dt &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{4t - 2}{2t^2 - 2t + 1}\, dt - \int_0^1 \frac{i}{2t^2 - 2t + 1}\, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\log|2t^2 - 2t + 1|\bigg|_{t = 0}^1 - \frac{i}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(t - \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{4}}\\
&= -\frac{i}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(t - \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{4}}\\
&= -\frac{i}{2}\cdot 2\arctan\left[2\left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\bigg|_{t = 0}^1\\
&= -\frac{\pi}{2}i.
\end{align}

A similar argument gives

$$\int_1^2 \frac{2t - 3 - i}{2t^2 - 6t + 5}\, dt = -\frac{\pi}{2}i.$$

Therefore

$$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-1} = -\frac{\pi}{2}i - \frac{\pi}{2}i = -\pi i.$$

Comment: you cant really factorise either of the denominators though...

Comment: can you at least tell me the final answer. I got something like $2ln(i)$ but I had to use WFA to solve them. It is so hard because I don't know how to cancel out the terms or factorise the denominators.

Comment: @snowman I hope this edit helps.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is that if you didn't manipulate the two integrals and just integrated how they were, you get $2\ln(i)$ but your answer is completely different. Why is that?

Comment: @snowman be careful -- which branch of the logarithm do you use?

Comment: natural logarithm. So im gessing logs do not work in imaginary numbers?

Comment: @snowman you're misunderstanding. The point is $\log z$ is multi-valued, so you need to specify which branch of the logarithm you're using when computing. I avoided those issues by essentially expressing the integrands in the form $f(t) + ig(t)$ and performing the usual integration.

Comment: When you brought the arctan out, why do you have 2 in front of the arctan? I even told WFA to differentiate $\arctan(2(t-\frac12))$ and it gave $\frac1{(t-1/2)^2+1/4}$. Where did the 2 come from...?

Comment: @snowman if you did the trig substitution $t - 1/2 = (1/2) \tan \theta$, you will see the $2$ come out. In general, $$\int \frac{dt}{(t - a)^2 + b^2} = \frac{1}{b}\arctan((t - a)/b) + C.$$

Comment: I think im gonna stop using wolfram because its really messing me up with everything!

Comment: @snowman good idea :-)